# "Stellung" - Einstellung or Position?

Tags: meaning-in-context

In the sentence
"Auch in dieser Rücksicht zeigt sich die **Stellung** zu vergangenen Systemen gewissermaßen günstiger",
is "Stellung" here referring to "**Einstellung**" (towards the systems) or rather to the "**Position**" (of the systems)?

Comment: A bit more context would be helpful.

Comment: @TheAwfulLanguage yes exactly... also i guess that "Rücksicht" in this type of sentence is most likely not right

Comment: Ich lese hier "Rücksicht" wie "Rückschau"; gewiss selten aber nicht falsch. Stellung und Einstellung sind ja oft das Gleiche, so auch hier.

Comment: Sounds like a machine translation from some language to German.

Comment: Falls es sich um eine automatische Übersetzung (wie z.B. in Google verfügbar) handeln sollte, vermute ich, dass es auf deutsch eher "Auch in dieser Hinsicht" heißen sollte. Vielleicht nach der Logik "respect ->re - spect -> Rück - sicht".

Comment: Meine Kommentare treffen es nicht. Vgl. Helges neue Frage https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/53832/r%c3%bccksicht-and-stellung.

Answer (score 1):

Without more context, this is some kind of educated guess, but the "zu" in *Stellung zu vergangenen Systemen* suggests that Einstellung is meant.
Also, "Rücksicht" is probably wrong, I would expect it to be "Rück**schau**" - to look (and evaluate) something a while after it happened.

Comment: Ob mit Rücksicht etwas wie Rückschau, Rückblick gemeint ist erklärt sich aus dem längeren, 160 Jahre alten Zitat in der Zweitfrage hier: https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/53832/r%c3%bccksicht-and-stellung die leider die erste Frage wieder mit aufwirft.

Answer (score 1):

"Einstellung" is a point of view or way of thinking, so it usually applies to a person. "Position" can refer to the place of an object, but also to the place of a person in a hierarchy. Unfortunately, the fragment doesn't show whether it refers to a person or an object.

Also "Rücksicht" in this context, especially with "vergangene" (past), almost certainly means "looking back (into the past)".

Comment: Rücksicht war nicht gefragt. 
Die Frage findest Du hier:  https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/53832/r%c3%bccksicht-and-stellung