# Rücksicht and Stellung

Tags: meaning-in-context

In the sentence "*Auch in dieser **Rücksicht** zeigt sich die **Stellung** zu vergangenen Systemen gewissermaßen günstiger*",

1. is "Stellung" here referring to "**Einstellung**" (towards the systems) or rather to the "**Position**" (of the systems)?
2. is "**ïn dieser Rücksicht**" referring to "**in this respect**" or rather to "**in this retrospective view**"?

I posted the question 1 also yesterday. There are two reasons for my reposting of question 1 and for my new question 2:
(i) Some of the answers asked for more context.
(ii) Some of the answers commented also upon the word "Rücksicht".

I do therefore now also raise question 2, while at the same time rendering the whole paragraph, instead of the specific sentence only.

The paragraph is quite extensive and is found in an old, philosophical text from 1858 titled *Das Problem der Philosophie und seine geschichtliche Evolution. Eine kritische Betrachtung von Prof. Dr. Monrad*:

*Wenn wir also früher gefunden haben, das die unmittelbaren Systeme in ihrem ursprünglichen Daseyn etwas Lebendigeres und Wahrhaftigeres sind, als sie in der späteren epitomirenden Reflexion erscheinen: so ist doch von einer andern Seite her eben diese Zusammenziehung und Verkürzung ein Vorzug, indem ein Wust von Aeußerlichkeiten und Zufälligkeiten beseitigt und eine weitere Uebersicht gewonnen wird.  Und selbst was die Innigkeit der subjectiven Ueberzeugung betrifft, so hat auch diese, so lange sie unmittelbar ist, insofern etwas Unfreies, einen Schein fatalistischer Nothwendigkeit, der aufgehoben werden muß.  Dem unmittelbaren — dogmatischen — Philosophen wird sein System gewissermaßen von seiner Zeitstellung und von seinem Genius gegeben; es ist sein Verhängniß, in welchem er mit seinem ganzen Geiste festgewurzelt ist.  Darum kann auch von Hingebung in vollstem Sinne die Rede nicht seyn; denn man gibt sich nur demjenigen hin, von dem man frei ist, dem man auch als etwas Selbstständiges gegenüberstehen könnte.  **Auch in dieser Rücksicht zeigt sich die Stellung zu vergangenen Systemen gewissermaßen günstiger**.  Denn das Vergangene ist als solches nicht mehr unmittelbare Wirklichkeit, die mich gefangen halten kann; es bedarf eben eines Aktes des freien Willens, um mich dahin zu versetzen, mich darin betrachtend zu versenken; der Zeitabstand und die zurückblickende Reflexion, durch welche ich dem betrachteten Gegenstand entzogen bin und unter mir habe, ist zwar noch nicht die wahre Freiheit, aber doch ein nothwendiger Durchgang für dieselbe.  Um ein System frei zu besitzen, nicht bloß davon besessen zu seyn, muß man seinem unmittelbaren Wirkungskreis entrückt seyn, wenigstens sich selbst davon abstrahiren können; und dieß gibt sich bei dem System einer anderen Zeit von selbst.*

Comment: Unklare Fragen heilt man an Ort und Stelle. Zwei Fragen in einer zu stellen, nur weil sie zufällig beide im gleichen Zitat begründet sind, ist keine gute Idee - die eine Frage könnte zufriedenstellend beantwortet werden, während die zweite offenbleibt. Soll man dann die Antwort akzeptieren? Hier eine zweite Frage zu eröffnen ist geboten, aber dann nicht wieder beide Fragen stellen, sondern bitte nur die eine. In der anderen bitte die Moderatoren bitten, dafür zu sorgen, dass sich das Publikum nicht an etwas fest beißt, was nicht gefragt war - passiert leider öfter.

Comment: Handelt es beim Verfasser um den norwegischen Theologen und Philosophen Marcus Jacob Monrad?

Comment: Answer to Paul Frost: Yes, indeed.

Answer (score 2):

"In dieser Rücksicht"  almost certainly means the same as the modern "in dieser Hinsicht".

Examples:

1. "Sprache in psychologischer Rücksicht" by Karl Philipp Moritz
   in: ΓΝΩΘΙ ΣΑΥΤΟΝ oder Magazin zur Erfahrungsseelenkunde als ein Lesebuch für Gelehrte und Ungelehrte. Mit Unterstützung mehrerer Wahrheitsfreunde herausgegeben von Karl Philipp Moritz, Erster Band, Erstes Stück., 1783 (http://www.literatur-live.de/salon/moritz.pdf)
2. https://www.linguee.de/deutsch-englisch/uebersetzung/in+dieser+r%C3%BCcksicht.html

See many other examples especially in older texts found via googling "in dieser Rücksicht".

"Stellung zu vergangenen Systemen" should mean the position that a philosopher takes on bygone philosophical systems.

Here is a modern example (not that I would recommend the website) of the expression "Stellung zu":

https://rotfrontkollektiv.wordpress.com/2013/09/23/die-nationalratswahl-2013-und-der-trotzkismus/

"Wahlen und die Stellung dazu sind ..."

"Die Stellung die sie zur ‚bürgerlichen Demokratie‘ einnehmen ..."

"Beide Zirkel haben in den Erklärungen keine klare Stellung zum ..."

"... und lässt ebenso jede Stellung zu System, Form und Methode der bürgerlichen Herrschaft beiseite."

Answer (score 0):

Made an attempt at a full, modernized translation, to get into the mood and capture the meaning of the sentence in question most accurately.

> So if we earlier found that the systems present then,
>   in their original forms, were more alive and truthful
>   than they appear in a later, recapitulating reflection,
>   then on the other side it is exactly this contraction and reduction
>   that removes a mess of random, unrelated aspects,
>   winning a clearer and farther reaching overview.
>
> Even ones own intimate personal conviction,
>   while it is ongoing, has something unfree,
>   a fatalistic urgency, that must be removed.
>
> A dogmatic philosopher is, in a manner of speaking,
>   given his system by his epoch and his own genius:
>   this is his fallacy, in which he is caught up with all his mind.
>
> It is therefore inappropriate to talk of "devotion" in all its meaning,
>   because you can only *devote* yourself to something which you are free of,
>   which you can face, at a distance, as an independent thing of its own.
>
> **In this respect, too, it is easier to position oneself towards past systems.**
>
> Because what's past is no longer a present reality that can capture me;
>   it requires an act of free will to put me back there, to sink in its reflection;
>   the temporal distance and the retrospection, by which I am remote of the
>   object of investigation, and thus have it *under* me, 
>   is not complete freedom, but still a necessary step on the path there.
>
> To own a system by free choice, you must be removed
>   from its direct sphere of influence,
>   to be able to at least abstract yourself from it;
>   in systems of a past, this is given automatically.

My impression is that Monrad plays with the word "Rücksicht" and leaves its double meaning of "retrospection" and "attitude" deliberately in place. "In this respect" comes a little easier, though.

"Position" clearly means the philosopher's attitude towards the system in question, and does not relate to spatial properties.